# cookie deleted when browser opens

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

We create a remember me cookie when the user logs in.  The login takes you to a different subdomamin. EX: Landing/Login page: www.mysite.com  Main page: www1.mysite.com.  The landing/login page is SSL while the main page is not.

If the user logs in and then logs out, which takes them back to the login/landing page, then the remember me cookie works fine.  However if they login and then close the browser  (not just close the tab but closing the whole thing) then the cookie is deleted.

NOTE: this is not due to browser settings.  We do not have delete cookies on close set.

While this happens on IE and chrome (not sure about FF) I have been testing on Chrome.  When I look in the chrome cookies file I can see that the cookie is not deleted when the browser is closed.  Instead it is deleted when the browser is opened, but before any of our server code is run.  Our client code is not deleting it either.

I can reproduce this in a single server test environment and the machineKey validationkey and decriptionKey are set in the web.config so that does not appear to be the problem.

The environment is ASP MVC 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: expiration not set/too early?

Comment: When you update the value of a cookie you have to update the expiration date as well.

Comment: That was it.  During a refactor our create cookie code lost the line that set the expiration.  Thanks